# Parsing the value and copying it to another column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

`column_1` (varchar) has values with the format like 1024 MB, 2048 MB etc. There also exits `column_2` (int). Now I would like to parse the value in `column_1` and update the `column_2` with values like 1024, 2048. I am using PostgreSQL. 
How do I do this ? I am fairly new to databases. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If your data is consistent, so that after a number it always contains a space and then something else, then the following expression will get you the number part:

```
split_part(original_size, ' ', 1)
```

This will split up your string along the spaces with the remaining chunks are indexed from 1 up to the last one, then the first one is picked.  There are, of course, other possibilities around, for example using a regex, which probably other will add later :)

Now you can construct your `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE size
   SET processed_size = split_part(original_size, ' ', 1);
```

Notice that there is no `WHERE` clause as you want to set the second column for every row in the table.

You find an example on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d5f9b/1).